# Accepts_nested_attributes_for join table of a has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, has-many-through

I have a has_many through relationship and am trying to save an attribute to a join table during the creation process.  I have read everything I could find online but can't seem to get anything to actually save. Rails 4 app using simple_form.

Model Setup

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, through: :requestables
  has_many :requestables
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests, through: :requestables, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :requestables

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :requestables
end

 class Requestable < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :line_item
   belongs_to :request
   validates :line_item_id, presence: true
   validates :request_id, presence: true
 end
```

Relevant part of form

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@request, @line_item]), remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name, :required => true, :autofocus => true  %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :requestables do |r| %>
      <%= r.input :quantity, :required => true %>
      <% end %>
 *rest of form*
```

controller (I am creating the LineItems on Index page).  I added the @line_item.requestables.build so I can include it in the form.

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @request = Request.find(params[:request_id])
  @line_item = @request.line_items.build
  @line_item.requestables.build
end

def create
  @request = Request.find(params[:request_id])
  @line_item = @request.line_items.create(line_item_params)
  if @line_item.save
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to :action => :index }
     format.js { flash.now[:success] = "Boom" }
    end
  else
    redirect :action => index
  end

private
  def line_item_params
    params.require(:line_item).permit(:name, :requestables_attributes => [:quantity])
  end 
end
```

I want to create a new LineItem and at the same time save the quantity to the join table / requestables.  I seem to have everything correct - when I don't include the quantity in the form, it correctly saves the LineItem and automatically creates the join table.  But when I use the about code, I get the following:

```
Processing by LineItemsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "line_item"=>{"name"=>"Pillow", "requestables_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"11"}}}, "commit"=>"Add to List", "request_id"=>"5"}
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Request Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
(0.0ms)  BEGIN
(0.0ms)  COMMIT
(0.0ms)  BEGIN
(0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/requests/5/line_items
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

It fails to save anything and just redirects.

I can achieve the result I want by updating the requestables with the quantity immediately after saving it, however this doesn't seem to be the Rails way and I can't get the quantity back for the edit form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've concluded based on a few days research that it is not possible to both create the join model using the rails association and simultaneously add an attribute to the join model.  Instead, I now create the join model and immediately update it with the attribute.

Comment: would you please answer your own question

Answer (score -3):

As you are using Rails4 , make sure you have

```
# attr_accessible
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

gem is in Gemfile and use attr_accessible

```
# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model----------
attr_accessible :name, :requestables_attributes
```

Rails 4 now uses [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

In order to use accepts_nested_attribute_for with Strong Parameters, you will need to specify which nested attributes should be whitelisted.

Comment: This does not answer the question, you are avoiding a Rails 4 feature and in the OP question he is defining white listed parameters.